# How to have the current date row always on top of excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, xlwings

I have a spreadsheet where people insert information daily in one row.

One row is a day and has several columns to fill.

[image]

We have a lot of data, so they have to scroll far-down.

I want to keep the old data and have the new row inserted on top automatically.

They might forget to insert some days so the new row should be the next date, it doesn't have to be today.

I don't mind using xlwings or VBA. That is why I wrote the question here. But the simplest option is prefered.

Comment: You have been a member for 9 years... And I hate to point you to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please post what you have tried so far. Keep these in mind while posting **1.** What were you expecting? **2.** What is not working? Include Error message if applicable and we will take it from there :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout In three weeks it's ten years :-) But I agree with Siddharth. Also your image seems to show the dates with the latest date at the bottom, not top as your question states.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that is what my question is about. How to get it to the top?

Comment: @SiddharthReverout It is not my field exactly and I haven't found anything that even attempts to solve anything, so how can I have errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on guesses and assumptions this could work.
I assume this is column A we see and that it's formatted as date.

If the dates is descending then this will look at the A1 value and loop until todays date and insert new rows and dates in each loop.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName")
    
    latest = CLng(ws.Range("A1").Value)
     
    While latest < CLng(Now())
        latest = latest + 1
        ws.Rows("1:1").Insert
        ws.Range("A1").Value = latest
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: THanks. What do you do with +1? You just add one integer to the timestamp? So this executes when you open the Workbook?

Comment: The +1 means add one day to the variable latest, and latest is the numeric representation of the date in cell A1. Today is 44375, tomorrow 44376 and so on. Yes this runs at workbook open if you add the code in the ThisWorkbook module.